# How can I create a VML textpath/textbox with linebreak?

Tags: dojo, raphael, vml, dojox.charting

I am using Dojo's charting library to create a piechart. The library falls back to VML for non SVG supporting browsers. The library is creating VML textpaths as so:

```
<v:textpath style=\"FONT: 8pt Tahoma; TEXT-DECORATION: none; v-text-align: center; v-rotate-letters: false; v-text-kern: true\" on = \"t\" string = \"HERE IS THE TEXT I WANT TO LINE BREAK\"></v:textpath>
```

Does anyone know how I can add a linebreak to the textpaths string? Thank you!!!

Comment: I did try this, thanks